# Django view that is supposed to be returning a file attachment is rendering in browser

Tags: django-views, attachment

I feel a bit like a nubcake because I'm certain I'm missing something pretty straightforward.

Problem: I have a django view that is supposed to be returning a file as a downloadable attachment, but every time I hit the view, it tries to render it in the browser as a page

It feels like the problem should be with the mimetype, but I'm fairly certain that I've set that correctly. That being said, this is my first time explicitly setting mimetypes, so I could easily be wrong.

Another blog post I read indicated that maybe it was a dev vs live server problem, but swapping this out onto an apache server didn't help.

Anyhoo, the code looks like this (most of my code for my view I've copy-pasta'd out of examples i've found):

```
def get_file(clss, request, obj):                                                                                                  
   path = obj.file.path                                                                                   
   fsock = open(path,"r")                                                                                                         
   content_type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type( path )                                                                          

   response = HttpResponse(fsock, content_type = content_type)                                                                    
   response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize( path )                                                  
   response['Content-Encoding'] = encoding                                                                                        
   response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s/' % smart_str(os.path.basename( path ) ) 

   return response
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Content-type of "application/x-download" for this. The Content-type tells the browser how to render the response, and you want the browser to "render" by saving the bits, not try to display them in a way appropriate to what's in the file.